# Lightning Sync Enabled for Gmail need remote settings and Google Admin?

Tags: lightning, salesforcedx, sync

Does enable lightning sync in Salesforce  and installing Chrome extension for gmail suite, will enable log in email option and create Contacts & Accounts in Salesforce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lightning Sync is for server-to-server sync of contacts and events (think calendar appointments). It does not require a browser extension or a user action. The Salesforce product option you're thinking about is unhelpfully called "[Gmail integration](http://salesforce.vidyard.com/watch/oGKxdxnyAyKfbmwXJeaZVV?)". You can use Gmail integration on its own and/or together with Lightning sync. Have a look at all available [options](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sfo_vs_email_connect.htm&type=5).

Comment: We are using both Gmail Integration and Lightning Sync together. If I only enable lightning sync option and do not do anything else like setting up remote site and generate google privacy key. Will this be enough or does it need to setup all other pieces as well?

Comment: On the Salesforce side, you will need to configure the remote site and add the Google key.